# extract unique numbers from column in a dataframe

Tags: r

I want to extract unique numbers from the column from a data frame. I have extracted numbers from different columns and got in into a different column in a data frame.
sample code :

```
library(dplyr)
df <- as.data.frame(rbind(c("12,15,19,15,12,16,41"),c("1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1")))
df1 <- unique(df)
```

Expected output is :

```
12,15,19,16,41  
1,2,3,4,5
```

Comment: I don't get your logic, from the first column you extract only unique numbers, from the second you extract only numbers... which appear once?

Comment: Data.frames are organized by row such that every column must have the same number of entries. That doesn't seem to match your desired output. Is there some other data structure that would work for you? What do you need to be able to do with the result?

Comment: Sorry I have edited my question: I want unique numbers only. Thanks,

Comment: unique numbers of each column? one column? or all rows? and you want you output as a dataframe? as vectors?

Comment: I want unique numbers from each observation. Each observations is independent of each other.

Comment: Your vector syntax is incorrect. `c("1,2,3")` produces a character vector of length one. You're looking for `c(1,2,3)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a list column in a dataframe, not sure if this is what you want:

```
list_col <- lapply(
  strsplit(as.character(df$V1), ","), 
  function(x) as.numeric(unique(x))
)

df1 <- data.frame(I(list_col))
df1
#       list_col
# 1 12, 15, ....
# 2 1, 2, 3,....

df1$list_col
# [[1]]
# [1] 12 15 19 16 41
#
# [[2]]
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 0):

We can split strings on comma (`,`) and extract only `unique` values from each.

```
df$new_col <- sapply(strsplit(df$V1, ","), function(x) toString(unique(x)))
df

#                    V1            new_col
#1 12,15,19,15,12,16,41 12, 15, 19, 16, 41
#2    1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1      1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- as.data.frame(rbind(c("12,15,19,15,12,16,41"),c("1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1")))

x <- apply(df, 1, function(x) eval(parse(text=paste0("c(", x, ")"))) )
sapply(x, function(x) as.numeric(unique(x)))
```

returns

```
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]   12    1
[2,]   15    2
[3,]   19    3
[4,]   16    4
[5,]   41    5
```